# JColorChooser RGB Tab with custom text

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, uimanager, jcolorchooser

I am customizing JColorChooser by modifying the UIManager's defaults for the JColorChooser tabs. I have successfully customized the labels and texts except the **Color Code** one.

[image: Color Code in JColorChooser's RGB tab]

I used the following code to modify the contents of the RGB tab.

```
UIManager.put("ColorChooser.rgbRedText", "Custom Red:");
UIManager.put("ColorChooser.rgbGreenText", "Custom Green:");
UIManager.put("ColorChooser.rgbBlueText", "Custom Blue:");
UIManager.put("ColorChooser.rgbAlphaText", "Custom Alpha:");
```

However, when I try the same thing for **Color Code** it doesn't work:

```
UIManager.put("ColorChooser.rgbColorCodeText", "Custom Color Code:");
```

How can I access UIManager to customize it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key for the color code field label is not `ColorChooser.rgbColorCodeText` but `ColorChooser.rgbHexCodeText`.

See the [ColorChooserPanel.buildChooser](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17/blob/4afbcaf55383ec2f5da53282a1547bac3d099e9d/src/java.desktop/share/classes/javax/swing/colorchooser/ColorChooserPanel.java#L135) and [ColorModel.getText](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17/blob/4afbcaf55383ec2f5da53282a1547bac3d099e9d/src/java.desktop/share/classes/javax/swing/colorchooser/ColorModel.java#L84) source code.

Comment: Might be nice to include how/where you found that information.